# SQL Query select optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm using ms sqlserver 2005.
i have a query that need to filter according to date.
lets say i have a table containing phone numbers and dates.
i need to provide a count number of phone numbers in a time frame (begin date and end date).
this phone numbers shouldn't be in the result count if they appear in the past.
i'm doing something like this :

```
select (phoneNumber) from someTbl
where phoneNumber not in (select phoneNumber from someTbl where date<@startDate)
```

This is looking not efficient at all to me (and it is taking too much time to preform resulting with some side effects that maybe should be presented in a different question)
 i have about 300K rows in someTbl that should be checked.

after i'm doing this check i need to check one more thing.
i have a past database that contains yet another 30K of phone numbers.
so i'm adding

```
and phoneNumber not in (select pastPhoneNumber from somePastTbl)
```

and that really nail the coffin or the last straw that break the camel or what ever phrase you are using to explain fatal state.

So i'm looking  for a better way to preform this 2 actions.

**UPDATE**
i have choose to go with Alexander's solution and ended up with this kind of query :

```
SELECT t.number
FROM tbl t
WHERE t.Date > @startDate
--this is a filter for different customers
AND t.userId in (
                    SELECT UserId
                    FROM Customer INNER JOIN UserToCustomer ON Customer.customerId = UserToCustomer.CustomerId 
                    Where customerName = @customer
                )
--this is the filter for past number
AND NOT EXISTS (                          
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM pastTbl t2
                  WHERE t2.Numbers = t.number                            
                )
  -- this is the filter for checking if the number appeared in the table before  startdate               
AND NOT EXISTS (                          
                  SELECT *
                  FROM tbl t3
                  WHERE t3.Date<@startDate and t.number=t3.number
                )
```

Thanks Gilad

Comment: What part of the query takes most time in the query execution plan? Is indexes provided? How long time does the query take and what is an acceptable timeframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option

```
SELECT t.phoneNumber
FROM SomeTbl t
WHERE t.date > @startDate
  AND NOT EXISTS (                          
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM SomePastTbl t2
                  WHERE t2.phoneNumber = t.phoneNumber                            
                  )
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the simple solution . i have adopted your approach for using NOT EXISTS in another filtering i needed to done. i will accept your answer though it is not complete but it is really copy paste to complete it with the different filter i needed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since its a not in just switch the less than to a greater than.

```
select phoneNumber from someTbl where date > @startDate
```

Next to filter out somePastTbl

```
select s1.phoneNumber from someTbl s1
LEFT JOIN somePastTbl s2 on s1.phoneNumber = s2.phonenumber
where s1.date > @startDate and s2 IS NULL
```

**UPDATE**

As Per comment:

Less than month of start date

```
SELECT COUNT(s1.phoneNumber) FROM someTbl s1
LEFT JOIN somePastTbl s2 on s1.phoneNumber = s2.phonenumber
where DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@startDate) < s1.date AND s1.date < @startDate and s2 IS NULL
```

Comment: hi. thabks for the quick response. i have used your second statement regarding the old data and it indeed improve the performance.

Comment: hi. thabks for the quick response. i have used your second statement regarding the old data and it indeed improve the performance. however , the first condition is not fulfilled. i need to check that a phone number present in the requested time frame  (lets say +12127773456 in the last month) is not present also before (if i have +12127773456 before 2 months also i shouldn't count the occurrence of it in current count). hope i made my self clearer.thanks

Comment: @gilad So if i understand you need to know where it existed less than a month of the start date?

Comment: yes you are correct and from your question it led me to use another NOT EXISTS statement eliminating same numbers with older date.   AND NOT EXISTS (                          
                  SELECT *
                  FROM tbl t3
                  WHERE t3.Date<@startDate                       and t.number=  t3.mobile _number)                         where t is the outer table

Comment: @gilad I have provided an update on the answer which should also give you what you need

Comment: hi . thanks for you time. i might have been not clear enough. the Less Than month was just an example of a number that is already in the table. i needed something to go over all the table and make sure the number appears only FROM startdate and if it doesn't (if it appears before startdate the query will not count it). Any way i think i have adopted Alexander way and it is working quite nice for my needs , so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

one simple index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SomeTbl_date_phoneNumber
    ON SomeTbl
(
    date ASC,
    phoneNumber ASC
)
```

then

```
SELECT phoneNumber FROM SomeTbl WHERE date > @startDate
EXCEPT
SELECT phoneNumber FROM SomePastTbl;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.i have these indexes already on this table.

Comment: @gilad I specify only one covering index, is the statement fast and doing what you want?

Comment: the statement is fast when i'm using it plain simple. when i add some inner join to the first select to filter by userId it get stuck again.

Comment: @gilad I don't see that condition in the question.

Comment: yes you are correct . i thought the main issue was the iteration over the old phone numbers  with every new phone number as i did so i didn't mention the other innerjoins. when i ran your code it was very fast but when i added two inner join to filter by userId too, it got stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

You want phone numbers whose *minimum* start date is greater than your start date.  This suggests aggregation at the phone number level before doing the count (or creating the list).

Here is one way, with the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select COUNT(*)
from (select t.phonenumber,
      from someTble t left outer join
           somePastTble pt
           on t.phonenumber = pt.phonenumber
      where pt.phonenumber is null
      having MIN(date) >= @startdate 
     ) t
```

You can also write this using window functions (SQL 2005 or greater).  Here is a version using `min()`:

```
  select COUNT(distinct t.phonenumber)
  from (select t.*, t.phonenumber, MIN(date) over (partition by phonenumber) as mindate
        from someTble t
       ) t left outer join
       somePastTble pt
       on t.phonenumber = pt.phonenumber
  where pt.phonenumber is null and mindate >= @startdate
```

Comment: hi . thanks for the effort. in the first option (i will stick to it - enough with learning new stuff while learning new stuff..) there is no consideration whether the number is in db before @startdate and then it shouldn't be counted.